# How to Limit the number of Threads in list<type>.asParallel in F#

Tags: f#

I've looked at a few examples in Stack Overflow etc and I can't seem to get my specific scenario working.

I want to iterate a list of 1500 items,but each item will hit the API so I want to limit the number of concurrent threads to about 6.

Is this the right way to do this?  I'm just afraid it won't limit the actual threads I need to.

```
    let fullOrders = 
        orders.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(6) |>
        Seq.map (fun (order) -> getOrderinfo(order) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily test this by using something like:

```
let orders = [ 0 .. 10 ]

let getOrderInfo a =
  printfn "Starting: %d" a
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
  printfn "Finished: %d" a
```

The first issue here is that `AsParallel` does not work with `Seq.map` (which is just normal synchronous iteration over a collection), so the following runs the tasks sequentially with no parallelism:

```
let fullOrders = 
    orders.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(6) 
    |> Seq.map (fun (order) -> getOrderInfo(order) )

fullOrders |> Seq.length
```

To make it parallel, you'd need to use the `Select` method on `ParallelQuery` instead, which does exactly what you wanted:

```
let fullOrders = 
  [0 .. 10].AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(6).Select(fun order ->
    getOrderInfo(order) )

fullOrders |> Seq.length
```

Note that I added `Seq.length` to the end just to force the evaluation of the (lazy) sequence.